# Using qsort / casting in C

Tags: c, casting, qsort

I'm attempting to use qsort() to sort an array of mine, but coming up with a weird error...

```
error: passing argument 4 of ‘qsort’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/stdlib.h:761: note: expected ‘__compar_fn_t’ but argument is of 
type ‘int (*)(struct Record *, struct Record *)’
```

Here is my function call:

```
qsort(arr, (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(struct Record)), sizeof(struct Record), compare);
```

And here is my compare method:

```
int compare (struct Record *a, struct Record *b){

return (a->key - b->key);
}
```

I know this is likely a casting issue - but I thought I could just pass the name of the comparative function itself..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look, the error is quite clear: `__compar_fn_t` has type `int(*)(const void*, const void*)` but your function is `int(*)(struct Record*, struct Record*)`. Quicksort doesn't know about the type of your array, so you have to use `void*` for your comparator arguments and then cast them to the appropriate types inside it:

```
int compare (const void *a, const void *b){
    struct Record const* a_r = (struct Record const*)a,
                       * b_r = (struct Record const*)b;

    return (a_r->key - b_r->key);
}
```

Comment: You declared `b_r` as a `struct Record`.

Comment: Attempted, but still no cigar... Same error: passing argument 4 of ‘qsort’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/stdlib.h:761: note: expected ‘__compar_fn_t’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(void *, void *)’

Comment: @katiea sorry, I forgot the `const`.

Comment: Currently: 

int compare (void *a, void *b){
    struct Record* a_r = (struct Record*)(a);
    struct Record* b_r = (struct Record*)(b);

    return (a_r->key - b_r->key);
}

Comment: @user3286380: Would you know why qsort might not seem to be working? My array has the proper information added, but qsort doesn't seem to be sorting the array based on said key of my Record Struct... Did I miss something regarding qsort?

Answer (score 1):

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(struct Record*)a -  *(struct Record*)b );
}
```

Comment: You can't drop the `struct` in `struct Record`.